# equivalent expression of nested multiple array iteration with java 8 lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was thinking a way to make a java 8 coding for this iterations:

```
if(rules.size()>0){
    for (int i=0;i<rules.size();i++) {
        for(AbstractProductInterface product:products){
          if(rules.get(i).getProductsToApply().contains(product.getClass()){
                productDiscounts.add(new ConcreteProductDecorator(product, rules.get(i),conditions.get(i)));
          }     
        }
    }
```

Comment: What’s the point of wrapping the loop with `if(rules.size()>0){…}`? Comparing `rules.size()` with `0` is exactly the first thing, the loop will do.

Comment: useless question, just focus on the request please, you can avoid the if condition for the purpose of my question.

Comment: Removing the obsolete `if` will improve your code much more than rewriting it to “make a java 8 coding”, whatever that means. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: you are not forced to write comments if you don't know the question...

Comment: You don’t have asked a question.

Comment: @NatherWebber you should delete your offensive comments, *especially* targeted at one of the most respected users on SO. Seriously, plz do.

Comment: you should delete your out of topic and ridicolous considerations

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code writing service? a part that is full of requested about how to make operations with lambda expressions, for sure stackoverflow is not your Cafe around the corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first I'll say this again here, those offensive comments are *really* bad, please delete them.

Second, your code relies on indexes and whatever solution you choose with `Stream`s is going to be very ugly and un-readadble compared to the clear and simple for loop you have at the moment.

I can only assume that this would work (I have not compiled it, since you have not provided neither the classes nor some test data):

```
IntStream.range(0, rules.size())
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(x -> products.stream()
                    .filter(p -> rules.get(x).getProductsToApply().contains(p.getClass()))
                    .map(y -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, y)))
            .map(e -> new ConcreteProductDecorator(e.getValue(), rules.get(e.getKey()), conditions.get(e.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Compare this verbosity with whatever you have in place right now...

Comment: thanks for the response, but for the comment I want the people can see the level of certain "experts"

Comment: don't you think that even if it is verbose, it can assure more performance with large array items?

Comment: @NatherWebber it *could*, but you would need **a lot** of data, unless you measure, it's really hard to say.

Comment: it is working, Thanks! could you explain better what are the intermediate operations?

Comment: @NatherWebber I dont your question... what should I explain better?

Comment: what is the box() and how you reproduce the index using maps

Comment: @NatherWebber `boxed` transforms from `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>`.  `flatMap` takes one single integer (index) and returns a `Stream` that consists of a `Map.Entry` where `Key` is this integer and value is a product (because of `contains(p.getClass())` it's only the one you care about). the last `map` just takes this entry and builds your needed obejct

Comment: thank you very much, I think it wasn't so easy to understand how to use "syncroinized" arrays  with lambda expression, so the box at the end is like a counter that is used for mapping object each one with their own index associated.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your iteration like as following in Java 8

```
    if (rules.size() > 0) {
      IntStream.of(rules.size()).forEach(i -> products.stream().filter(product -> rules.get(i).getProductsToApply().contains(product.getClass())).forEach(product -> productDiscounts.add(new ConcreteProductDecorator(product, rules.get(i), conditions.get(i)))));
    }
```